# PHP explode() and If statement

Tags: php, if-statement, explode

I literally spent 6 hours trying to find this out. I have the code below:

```
$pieces3 = explode(":", $value2);
$checkiftime = $pieces3[0];
if ($checkiftime == 'time')
{
echo "Yes!";
}
else
{
echo "Oh no!";
}
```

$value2 contains:

```
" 'time': 1376952971"
```

I'm pretty sure the statement should be true but for some reasons, I keep getting false (oh no!)

> if ($checkiftime == 'time')

What could be wrong? I already tried using double quotes for $checkiftime=="time" but still no avail.

EDIT:

I tried doing Vardumps after the explode:

```
var_dump($pieces3);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($value2);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($pieces3[0]);
echo "<br>";
```

And resulted with:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(13) " 'time'" [1]=> string(11) " 1376952971" } 
string(25) " 'time': 1376952971" 
string(13) " 'time'"
```

I'm not sure why 'time' shows as String(13), I see that blank space, could that be a special character containing more than 1 hidden string? I did a trim() but it doesn't seem to change anything.

EDIT2:

Thanks everyone, below is the part of the code that I modified and it worked great:

```
$checkiftime = trim($pieces3[0], " '\t\n\r\0\x0B");
if ($checkiftime == 'time')
```

Comment: `var_dump($pieces3);` - Can you post result formatted in question please?

Comment: Just ran your exact code, using `$value2 = "time: 1376952971"` and it works as expected. The result is `Yes!`

Comment: http://codepad.org/yGutpX7h

Comment: have you tried trim($checkiftime) before comparing it?

Comment: Also, try doing something simple like echo "[$checkiftime]";  Then you can do the comparison with your human brain.

Comment: Try exact matching `if ($checkiftime === 'time')`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: How is that improving the situation? If == returns false already, === will too.

Comment: We need to see more code. This isn't enough to go on, including where `time` is being pulled in from.

Comment: +1 @MarkM. It also works in many a PHP versions: http://3v4l.org/sZo1U

Comment: My hunch is that `$value2` isn't **exactly** what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have edited my post above, please help me check the vardump results

Comment: So it's pretty clear that `$value2` actually contains `" 'time': 1376952971"` which is certainly not what you expect it to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the main problem is that `$value2` contained an unexpected value.

It simply looks like you need to sanitise the string, removing any characters that might get in the way of your check (such as space and apostrophe / single-quote). Try this...

```
$checkiftime = trim($pieces3[0], " '\t\n\r\0\x0B");
```

See [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/function.trim.php). Demo here - http://ideone.com/uVEDXM

Alternatively, you could simply use a regular expression match to check the entire string, eg

```
if (preg_match('/^\W*time\W*: (\d+)$/', $value2, $matches)) {
    echo 'Yes!', PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($matches); // $matches[1] contains the numeric value 1376952971
}
```

Demo - http://ideone.com/025vAV

Comment: Thanks Phil. That would only remove the ' before the word time wouldn't it? How about the ' after the word time? Also is that a regular blank space before the word 'time'? I'm asking because it is showing as String(13) when it only contains 7 characters, so I'm thinking that blank space consist of 6 characters.

Comment: @user3613603 Read the manual for `trim()`, it removes leading and trailing characters. You are correct about the string length being longer than expected though the information you've pasted into your question only contains a normal space character. I've updated my answer to be more comprehensive

Comment: Hi Phil, the $checkiftime = trim($pieces3[0], " '\t\n\r\0\x0B"); did the trick. So Ibelieve that blank space is a special character? Probably counting as more than 1 character? It sounds weird but your code worked so that's the only explanation I can think of

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a space in the beginning of your 'time' or why you're keeping the single quotes around it, but here is the code that will produce a yes based on how it looks like you're setting it up:
http://codepad.org/T8yw8Ou5

Consider using JSON for a situation like this!

Comment: Hi Ramsey, that is actually a piece of data from a JSON log file. I just used explode() to strip out the " 'time': 215416541654" and will be converting that unix timestamp to date format

Answer (score 0):

```
$value2 = " 'time': 1376952971";

if( stristr( $value2 ,'time' ) === FALSE )
{
    echo "Oh no!";
}
else
{
    echo "Yes!";
}
```

The above checks if string `time` is present in the `$value2` . But if you need the time you could :

```
echo ( stristr( $value2 ,"'time':" ) === FALSE
        ? ''
        : trim( str_replace( "'time':" ,'' ,$value2 ) )
     );
```

Comment: This look's interesting, correct me if I'm wrong but this checks if the word "time" can be found in $value2 string?

Comment: Sure , it finds the first occurrence of the string `time` in `$value2` . [stristr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) .

Comment: You could try this : `echo ( stristr( $value2 ,"'time':" ) === FALSE ? '' : trim( str_replace( "'time':" ,'' ,$value2 ) ) );`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be part of some JSON data, except that it's malformed in that it uses single-quoted strings (which is valid in JavaScript but not valid in JSON). If we crudely replace single quotes with double quotes, and wrap it in `{}` to make it a complete object, it's easy to parse this string with json_decode(), which will handle variations in formatting and space characters that blunt splitting with explode() cannot:

```
$value = " 'time': 1376952971";
$value = json_decode('{' . strtr($value, "'", '"') . '}');
echo $value->time;
// Outputs: 1376952971
```

Comment: Actually, it IS a JSON file. I just replaced the double quotes as it is part of my process

Comment: This is actually interesting, got a question though. What if you're given this JSON string:

Comment: This is actually interesting, got a question though. What if you're given this JSON string:

`"Team_Items":{
"Army":{
"Paladins":{
"325648":0,
"546545":4
},
"Knights":{
"325648":-2,
"546545":0
}
}
}`

Can you use json_decode and get these items and values and their sub items and values and print them?

Comment: can I do `echo $value->325648; result is 0` or `echo $value->Paladins; result is "325648":0, "546545":4`

Comment: @user3613603 Yes, although that data must be wrapped in an outer `{}` to be a complete JSON string. If you have that string in `$value` then you can do: `$value = json_decode('{' . $value . '}');`. And then `echo $value->Team_Items->Army->Paladins->{546545};` will display `4`, and `print_r($value);` will echo the whole structure.

Comment: awesome! Also I was able to search and found this http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=860 . You gave me an idea that JSON logs can be easily parsed, never thought of that lol

Answer (score -1):

Your time value has single quotes around it, **within the string**.  So, you'd need to make your comparison:

```
$checkiftime = trim($checkiftime, " \t\n\r\0\x0B");
if ($checkiftime == "'time'") {
...
}
```

This is probably a good lesson in examining your values before asking a question about it  :)

You can remove the single quotes if you want:

```
$checkiftime = str_replace("'", "", $checkiftime);
```

Comment: There's also some whitespace characters though it seems they are more than simply ASCII space

Comment: @Phil That's what the trim() is for

Comment: This did not work for me. I should probably post the entire code but it contains sensitive information so I might need to modify it. I tried trim, the result is the same.

Comment: Did you copy the == "'time'" exactly (including the single quotes), and put the trim() function before it?

Comment: Also, if you put the str_replace function in there, before the comparison, you need to remove the single quotes from the == "'time'" portion

Comment: Oh, just read a previous answer.  Yeah, you probably have some extra spacing characters in there.  I modified the trim function, using something similar to what another user posted.

Comment: Yes I did that exactly, but it's doing the same. Phil's code worked as expected however, so I'm thinking there are special characters we didn't see? The data " 'time': 165165154" is actually a piece taken from a JSON server log file and that file seem to lag much when I view it in txt even though it's plain text (huge amount). So those special characters might exist in it somehow, causing it to lag much